# Why am I getting `middleware is not a function' in redux?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am setting up a simple React/Redux app.  Here is my setup:

```js
var {createStore, applyMiddleware } = require('redux')
var thunkMiddleware = require('redux-thunk')
var store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
)

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
          <div className="app">
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/Test' component={Test}/>
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, here are my reducers:

```js
var {combineReducers} = require('redux')

const carlist = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'LOAD':
      return action.test
    default:
      return state
  }
}
module.exports = combineReducers({carlist})
```

When I run my app, I get this error:

> applyMiddleware.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: middleware is not a function

What am I missing?

Comment: One possibility is that you forgot npm install --save redux-thunk ?

Comment: No, I thought about that and I checked.  I even added a `console.log(thunkMiddleware)` for a sanity check and it logged out

Answer (score 5):

the problem looks like it might be here:

`var thunkMiddleware = require('redux-thunk')`

Your middleware -- here `thunkMiddleware` -- is not a function, suggesting that it is not being pulled from the package. You should try:

`var thunkMiddleware = require('redux-thunk').default`

Or, try using ES6 module syntax (since you are already using ES6 features):

`import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'`

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when using `redux-logger`

I had just upgraded my packages and change

```
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
```

to

```
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
```